# What is the state of the art in html5 geospatial applications?

Tags: web-mapping, geospatial-pdf

I am very interested in the HTML5 `canvas` element for maps; work like [Cartagen](http://cartagen.org/) from an MIT Media Lab researcher looks very promising, for example.  There is some interesting SVG based work at [carto.net](http://www.carto.net/).  `WebSocket` seems like a fantastic API for live geospatial data.  I have done a few HTML5 experiments, for example [here](http://sfgeo.org/data/contrib/efishpjs/), with Flickr and Picasa data.  What are people getting up to with these new technologies, or what have you tried?

Comment: Adding to the list of examples: http://rlat.kew.org/ (via http://www.fosslc.org/drupal/content/html5-rich-geospatial-applications-web)

Comment: There is an open access [article](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/content/9/1/14) in IJHG's [Web GIS in practice](http://www.ij-healthgeographics.com/series/1476-072X-Gis) series covering HTML5 & Cartagen

Answer (score 13):

[OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) can use the HTML5 `canvas` element for [rendering](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Renderer/Canvas-js.html).

Answer (score 7):

HTML5 Rocks has some good interactive examples with SVG,Mapping,API and Database requests.

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide10
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide14

Not a Map but SVG - but would be good for Mapping!
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide27

Answer (score 5):

I quite like this example that does [live raster reprojection/warping](http://examples.maptiler.org/map-reprojection-html5-canvas/) in an html5 `canvas`.

Comment: seems like the link is broken

Comment: The *link* works for me, today. It is slow though, and the script a the other end doesn't seem to do anything. So -1 until someone puts up or locates a new version somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [Georelated](http://www.georelated.com/) blog, which has a series of articles on the state of the art of web mapping. It contains nice reviews of whats possible and the technology available for truely forward thinking web mapping.

1. Info on Silverlight v flash v html5
2. Browser based 3d web mapping
3. Globes in HTML5
4. Alternatives to tiled image maps and the power of vectors

Answer (score 4):

Check also [D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/). Not really a geospatial-focused library but there is some example with thematic maps. Built on SVG. The same author developed Polymaps.

Answer (score 3):

3D web Mapping using Web GL -

http://www.georelated.com/2011/10/rise-of-globe-in-web-mapping.html

Good Examples and links to WebGL open source toolkits

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Kartograph](http://kartograph.org/).  It's a two shot program:

1. Take some Geospatial data like a shapefile and run it through Kartograph.py.  That will turn it into an SVG file.
2. Use Kartograph.js to make it pretty in a browser.  Add thematic elements, animation, fancy fonts, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You may find also some useful resources in the SVGOpen conference:

- http://www.svgopen.org/2011/papers/8-Even_faster_web_mapping/index.html
- http://www.svgopen.org/2011/presentations/8-Even_faster_web_mapping/index.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Esri have some [HTML5 samples](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/index.html#html5) on the Javascript API samples page (select from bottom of the tree).  Making use of l[ocal storage for bookmarks](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/exp/exp_bookmarks_stored_client_side.html) is impressive (at the time of writing this).

Answer (score 1):

Late 2011: http://bl.ocks.org/1392560 (d3 rendering geojson as an interactive, draggable world map svg).

Answer (score 1):

http://osmbuildings.org displays 2.5D with HTML5 and Leaflet which looks impressive by results and speed

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty impressed by the work of [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/) and [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) that Showcase some really nice web mapping applications based on HTML5 and JavaScript Technology. Leaflet is an Open-Source JavaScript Library for Mobile-Friendly Interactive Maps.