# HTML5 maps with dynamic data instead of Flash

Tags: maps, html

I was wanting to create maps on our site similar to http://globaledge.msu.edu/Countries/Rankings except that we want the maps to be HTML/HTML5 instead of Flash. (The above site is the site that I'm working on also) The data is dynamic and gets updated periodically, but there's no set time, I just update the database. Any help would be much appreciated. I've looked at MapBox, but they seem to be one time only type of maps and I'd have to create a different map for each variable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for state-of-the-art developments in HTML5 dynamic map applications, [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/1224/230) has quite a few resources.

Personally, I'd say look into [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/). It is a great Javascript mapping library that utilizes the `canvas` element. Hook it up with [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) or [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/), and you should  be able to "just update the database" similar to how you do now.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for some pure-HTML way to display a map myself and stumbled upon this one
[Fla-shop.com HTML5-powered JavaScript Map](http://www.fla-shop.com/products/html5/united-states/us/)

Answer (score 0):

The map package at the Fla-shop link is excellent, I believe you have the option to purchase a single map for $70 or a bundle of 10 various colors for $100, they are extremely easy to install and in my view saved me so much time the purchase price was a no brainer as it saved me so much time.

The other benefit you will get is you can change the font sizes, colors and links in the settings file so you will be able to customize your own map if you wish and have this as a basis for future maps so all the heavy lifting is done for you.