# Fast data representation on the vector layers

Tags: openlayers-2, data, vector, visualisation

I have found an interesting article about how `HTML5` supports representation on large datasets.
Article can be found [here](http://www.giscloud.com/blog/gis-cloud-starts-html5-mapping-revolution). In the article it is said that `HTML5` and feature simplification can increasingly improve visualization speed. Does anybody knows about the source code (or just explain what is needed to be done to reach such results) or suggest how `OpenLayers` supports feature simplification?

Comment: Thanks for posting the link to the article! I don't think that OL supports <canvas> rendering yet. However, they state that their code could be ported to OL. Apart from that wouldn't it make more sense to do the simplification at server level, i.e. in WFS? Why lift all that data over to the client, to then not show it?

Answer (score 5):

Most of the heavy lifting is done on the server side.

A really complete run down of technically how this is achieved at [Creating Vector Polygons with rendering performance like GISCloud?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/how-to-create-vector-polygons-at-the-same-amazing-speeds-giscloud-is-able-to-ren)

As for supporting this rendering, OpenLayers has support for the HTML5 Canvas element, 
as per [What is the state of the art in html5 geospatial applications?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/what-is-the-state-of-the-art-in-html5-geospatial-applications), so with additional client side code, it too could support this type of vector data.

Unfortunatley, aside from GisClouds paid for offerings, I haven't seen anything on the opensource server side of things that supports serving up this type of rendering format.